# Alternatives to Adobe Reader Mobile 9 SDK to read DRM-protected ebooks

Tags: android, mobile, drm

I would like to develop an Android app that can read DRM-protected ebooks (pdf and epub).

I know this can be accomplished by using Adobe Reader Mobile 9 SDK but unfortunately it is quite expense to have a license for it ($75,000 per year).

So I'm looking for other alternatives, are there any?

Answer (score 1):

You may visit to Datalogics, because you can get a white label license of SDK much cheaper than original price, http://www.datalogics.com/products/rmsdk/.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no alternative. The reason is that you need to get your reader app approved by Adobe before it can work with the signing servers. To get the approval, you need to have built your app using RMSDK 9.